# Windows WSL yarn command appends folder name at end of import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, linux, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have Windows WSL and i'm trying to run a project via `yarn start`

The problem is that somehow the WSL replaces a dynamic import file with the folder name.

The file in discussion is

`C:/Projects/project/packages/v1/components/Viewer/General/Tab/Modal`
And the file is thrown an error in console is

Cannot find file: 'ActivateAlertModal.tsx' does not match the corresponding name on disk:
`mnt/c/Projects/project/packages/v1/components/Viewer/General/Tab/folder-name`

This makes no sense for me.
What useful information i can also give is that i have two diffrent folders with same project, the first on works just fine, and the second throws this error. I think that it might be due to the fact that i have same files in diffrent folders and somehow it conflicts?

Comment: What does `which yarn` show?

Comment: /home/user/ .yarn/bin/yarn